# Trying to emplace functor in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I got my inventory

```
std::unordered_map<std::reference_wrapper<Item>, int, ItemHasher> items;
```

`ItemHasher` is

```
struct ItemHasher
{
    std::size_t operator()(const std::reference_wrapper<Item>& item) const
    {
        return item.get().getHash();
    }
};
```

How to emplace item in my map?
I tried

```
items.try_emplace(item, 1, /*Different variants*/);
```

But it isn't working as it should.

Comment: And why doesn't it work? Does it compile? Provide a [mcve] please.

Comment: For example if I tried `items.try_emplace(item, 1, ItemHasher);`
warning error C2275: 'ItemHasher': illegal use of this type as an expression
If `items.try_emplace(item, 1, 6546546);`
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'int'
error C2439: 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::second': member could not be initialized.

I think i need to overload something

Answer (score 0):

`unordered_map` stores the hasher it uses already. It makes scant sense to pass another one to `try_emplace`.

```
items.try_emplace(item, 1);
```